# Using Composer for CakePHP and dependencies: overall strategy, project structure and `.gitignore`

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I would like my CakePHP project to use best practices. Currently we have our PHP dependencies checked into our project's repo, and i don't like that.

I want the project to leverage Composer, but i don't understand the proper strategy.

First, there is the **[official CakePHP repo](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/)**:

- `composer.json` is in the project root.
- There are `/vendors/` and `/plugins/` and they are under `.gitignore`.
- `/app/Vendor/` and `/app/Plugin/` are not ignored.

Then, there's an **[app-template](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/app-template)** boilerplate from FriendsOfCake:

- `composer.json` is in the project root.
- There are no `/vendors/` or `/plugins/`.
- `/app/Vendor/` and `/app/Plugin/` are under `.gitignore`.

Lastly, there's **[cakephp-composer](https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-composer)**, an active project. It implies that:

- `composer.json` is in `/app/`.
- The plugin itself is supposed to be installed by hand into `/app/Plugin/`.
- Readme does not explain `.gitignore` strategy, but plugin author [says](https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-composer/issues/6#issuecomment-13110872) that `/app/Vendor/` and `/app/Plugin/` should be ignored.

cakephp-composer is the weirdest thing. How am i supposed to fetch CakePHP and cakephp-composer after cloning my project?

I want to achieve the following:

1. My project repo contains only source code of the project itself. Any code that is versioned somewhere else, e. g. CakePHP framework and CakePHP plugins, should not appear in my repo.
2. After cloning my project's repo to a new location, i want to fetch all PHP dependencies, including CakePHP and its plugins, with a single Composer command. No manual downloading/cloning. The project should start working right after Composer finishes its job.
3. I really like the [app-template](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/app-template) boilerplate from FriendsOfCake. It looks simple and reasonable to me. So i wish my project structure were as close to app-template as possible.

I don't understand and request explanations for the following things:

1. Where is the folder for Composer to fetch dependencies into configured? Composer docs mention "PSR-4" and i (being a frontend dev coming from the Ruby world) don't have a slightest idea what that is.
2. What folders should be put under `.gitignore`?
3. Do i really need [cakephp-composer](https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-composer)? I hope that i don't!
4. How do i configure `composer.json` to fetch plugins with Composer, especially if i don't use cakephp-composer? It might be as simple as just mentioning package names under `require`, but how do i tell Composer whether plugins should go under `app/Vendor/` and `app/Plugin/`? Oh, and where should they go?
5. How do i properly include CakePHP and CakePHP plugins fetched by Composer into my project?

For an example CakePHP plugin to be fetched by Composer, take [haml](https://github.com/TiuTalk/haml). It's what i need for my frontend work and it has its own Composer dependency.

Comment: `composer.json is in /app/` - that is right. Check out existing CakePHP2.x projects and how they handled it: [cakephp-sandbox](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-sandbox) for example - Also, read the official documentation, its pretty clear from that: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, there's several questions there... I'll try to answer a few.

First and foremost, you should be clear on wether you want to use CakePHP 2.X, or CakePHP 3.0.  I assume since you're talking about an existing project, you mean Cake 2.X - which wasn't built with composer in mind. Cake 3.0 was built with composer in mind, so if upgrading to that is an option, I assume it'll be nicer (I haven't used 3.0 yet myself)

Here's a simplified example `composer.json` file from one of my projects:

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "require": {
        "cakedc/migrations": "2.2.2",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.2.1",
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "app/Vendor/"
    },
    "extra": {
       "installer-paths": {
         "app/Plugin/Migrations": ["cakedc/migrations"],
         "app/Plugin/DebugKit": ["cakephp/debug_kit"],
       }
     }

}
```

1. see the line `"vendor-dir": "app/Vendor/"` - that's where I've configured composer to put it's packages, by default, in my `app/Vendor/` folder.
2. What goes in .gitignore... we'll come back to that.
3. No, you don't need this.
4. See the line `"installer-paths": {`? That's where I've configured composer to put specific CakePHP plugins in Cake's plugins dir, as opposed to the default `app/Vendor/` which I mentioned in 1.
5. For CakePHP Plugins - see 4. For CakePHP itself, I haven't personally done it. I did try at one point and found the setup to be not playing nicely with one of my plugins, so I gave up on it. However, you should be able to use the same principals as above.

Now, coming back to 2. what should be in your .gitignore? Anything that has contents completely maintained by composer - in my case, that's `app/Vendor/`, and `app/Plugin/`. That assumes that ALL the contents of those folders is maintained by composer. If you had eg. one plugin that you'd added manually, then you couldn't ignore the whole folder - you'd have to ignore only the specific plugins installed with composer.

PS - I personally delete the root `vendor/` and `plugins/` folders - I don't use them at all.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed reply, Joshua! Where do you keep your `composer.json`? And where does `installer-paths` come from? It's not mentioned in [Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md).

Comment: composer.json should go in the root of your project. And installer-paths: see https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md

Comment: There's an easier way to set the installer paths (https://github.com/taalendigitaal/composer-installers#custom-install-paths): `"installer-paths": { "app/Plugin/{$name}/": ["type:cakephp-plugin"] }`